# Enumerating over an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, enumerate

I'm trying to enumerate over an array in C, much like pythons enumerate method.

```
static void enumerate(char *choices[])
{
    int i;
    int length = sizeof(choices)/sizeof(*choices);

    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        printf("[%d] %s\n", i, choices[i]);
    }
}
```

How I'd expect this to work is, create an array (or list): `char *test[] = {"test", "testing};` then pass that array (or list) to the function: `enumerate(test);` and the expected output should be:

```
[0] test
[1] testing
```

However when I try this, the output I'm getting is just the first item in the array:

```
[0] test
```

What am I doing wrong to where this will not work as I'd expect it to?

Comment: That's a classical beginner error. `sizeof` can't know the size of the array when given as a pointer.

Comment: Another classical beginner error is not printffing out the value of length as a debug measure.

Comment: The implicit conversion of the type of `sizeof` to `int` is also a bit naughty.

Comment: There is no array in your function! Do some research about this statement and think about the implications. (also: `enumerate` is not a _method_, but a _function_ and your function is very different from that Python function)